# Github to google colab

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

So I wanted to clone a [YoutubeDLC](https://github.com/blackjack4494/yt-dlc) repository to Google colab

Can anyone help me ?

this is the colab notebook I have

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1np5r05AiYU3DGvRcvd1dga2st6KHrw5O

Basically I want the YTDLC Notebook to work like the [YoutubleDL Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13G4Q8scsCPh6r9YqX39hqEUu7axq4Xr2) which I have

Answer (score 0):

For you to clone a repository in colab, just type the command below in a cell.

```
%%shell
git clone https://github.com/escudero/TFYolo.git
```

Comment: does it create the ipynb file ?